# "how to Receive SOUND in PYTHON and how to differentiate it according to its Frequency "

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new-bee in PYTHON and working on a small project,.
I am also trying pyaudio but can't able to use it.
" TO RECIVE A SOUND IN PYTHON LANGUAGE BY MICROPHONE AND THEN DIFFENTIATE IT ACCORDING TO FREQUENCY AND ONLY SELECT THE SPECIFIC FREQUENCY SOUND LIKE "17000Hz" or it is to be good if I only receive this Frequency of sound in PYTHON and please share syntax and lib name or an example set of code so it is good for me thank you,

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: actually nothing , i m still find a function which Receive audio and capable to differentiate the input sound according to Frequency , or any method or algorithm or trick which able to do this

Comment: You can use scipy to open a .wav file and perform an FFT on the sound to get frequency. If you try something out with this process I am happy to help, I am not going to write an entire code for it though.

Comment: thanks for your  suggestions but i have to record a sound using MICROPHONE and simultaneously sort out the frequency than according to sound pattern action is perform not by .wav file